# How to generate data for future price predictions with Linear regression and Python

Tags: python, keras, pandas, linear-regression

I have written the following Python code that makes predictions using linear regression model. However, I'll appreciate you pointing out what went wrong with how I generated data['X_forecast']. I'm sensing I might be wrong on the way I pulled out data['X_forecast']. Consider the following code which makes a one-day prediction:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

start_date = '01/01/2004'
end_date = date.today()
ticker = 'TSLA'
data_source = 'yahoo' 
days_into_the_future = 1
test_size = 0.25

df = web.DataReader(ticker, data_source, start_date, end_date)
data = {}
data['df'] = df.copy()
data['df']['target'] = data['df']['Adj Close'].shift(-days_into_the_future)
data['df'] = data['df'].drop(['Volume','Adj Close','Close'],1)
data['X_forecast'] = data['df'].iloc[-days_into_the_future:,:-1]
data['df'] = data['df'].dropna()
data['feature'] = data['df'].drop(['target'],1)
data['target'] = data['df'].iloc[:,-1]

X = np.array(data['feature'])
y = np.array(data['target'])
timefeatures = data['feature'].index  

# split the dataset into training & testing sets by date
train_samples = int((1 - test_size) * len(X))
data["X_train"] = X[:train_samples]
data["y_train"] = y[:train_samples]
data["X_test"]  = X[train_samples:]
data["y_test"]  = y[train_samples:]
data["dates_train"] = timefeatures[:train_samples] # Extract the dates of train and test set dates
data["dates_test"] = timefeatures[train_samples:]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
history = model.fit(data['X_train'],data['y_train']) 

predictionlineReg = history.predict(data['X_test'])  # Linear regression
predictionlineRegfuture = history.predict(data['X_forecast'])
```

I know how to create features as technical indicators and perform features/training set scaling. However,  I am more concerned about the data I used to predict into the future. How would you have generated your own data['X_forecast'], or which way is ideal?